# Double quotes in Json String replaced in freemarker file

Tags: json, escaping, freemarker, double-quotes, struts2-jquery-grid

In an action class, I get a list of beans in conventional manner. Then I use Gson to convert this object list in a json string.
This works well (as you can see as follow):

```
"{ "employees" : [{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, {"firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" } , { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" } ]}";
```

Finally, in my freemarker file I get this variable (String JSon) but, in it, all double quotes have been replaced with '& quote;'.

```
<@sjg.grid id="gridtable"
 caption="My title"
 dataType="json"
 href="${remoteurl}"
 pager="true"
 gridModel="${employeesInJsonString?js_string}"
 rowList="10,15,20"
 rowNum="15"
 rownumbers="true">

<sjg:gridColumn name="firstName" index="firstName" title="FirstName" sortable="false"/>
<sjg:gridColumn name="lastName" index="lastName" title="LastName" sortable="false"/>
```

The resulting String is the following:

```
"{ & quote;employees& quote; : [{ & quote;firstName& quote;:& quote;John& quote; , & quote;lastName& quote;:& quote;Doe& quote; }, {& quote;firstName& quote;:& quote;Anna& quote; , & quote;lastName& quote;:& quote;Smith& quote; } , { & quote;firstName& quote;:& quote;Peter" , & quote;lastName& quote;:& quote;Jones& quote; } ]}";
```

How to keep out this transformation?

PS: I already tried to prefix all double quotes by a backslash to escape the character but the result is the same (resultJsonString = jsonString.replaceAll("\"", "\\"")).

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: How about replacing all double quotes to "& quote;" just after converting into String using Gson ?

Comment: The value is not printed in the shown template. I guess it's printed in `sjg.grid`, which we don't see here. Also, in what context do you see that output? Are you sure it's incorrect to be HTML-escaped there? BTW, the `gridModel` assignment looks strange too... `gridModel=employeesInJsonString` would be cleaner, assuming you are indeed supposed to pass in the JSON itself. (Same for `href`; can be written simply as `href=remoteurl`.)

Comment: I see this output in the source code of the HTML page displayed (options_gridtable.jsonReader.root="theOutput").

The assignment use freemarker notation and it looks like to work well.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

i think what you are looking for is simply `${yourvar?no_esc}`